# How to make ViewPager square sized to screen width?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager that I want to take up the entire width of the phone screen, however much that is. I want the height of the ViewPager to then match the width so the whole thing is square, but cannot figure out how to do this.

I have tried combinations of weight, fixed height, match_parent, wrap_content but nothing seems to achieve this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Display`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html) to get screen size in pixels.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = width;
```

Then create [`LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html) and set them to your [`ViewPager.`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

```
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(width,height);
mViewPager.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

You might also want to check which value is less, width or height.

Adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/how-to-get-screen-dimensions)

Comment: So this would be the best practice way to achieve this? There is no built in way to do it without manually setting heights?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way compatible with xml and no config needed:

```
public class SquareViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public SquareViewPager(final Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareViewPager(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final int width = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(),widthMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, width);
    }

    @Override protected void onSizeChanged(final int w, final int h, final int oldw, final int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, w, oldw, oldh);
    }
}
```

And then:

```
<my.package.SquareViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```